# How to hide http request header?

Tags: laravel, http, vue.js

I have an auth token in my http-request header (look screen)

[image: screenshot]

But I need to hide this header so that no one can get this token from the console. How can i do this?

Comment: You simply cannot. What makes you think you need to hide it?

Comment: as Phil said, you cant. You can make things little safer with HTTPS and one-time-use only token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to hide this token. However if you use HTTPS, the connection to your website is secure and no one in the middle can see it. The token is only visible to the user that it belongs to, so it poses no security risk as the user should have access to it.

Being able to inspect the requests sent is a feature of the browser and it is in no way related to your site.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that u can see data over HTTPS, if u have access to the client computer or mobile device. Mobile devices are most vulnerable, because u share token to the device and then someone else use is

With Fiddler u can see all the https data